# Python importing from module

Tags: python, import

So I started to code my own python module however i started to run into some issues with circular dependencies. I used to import all functions with `from mymodule import *` and that for a bunch of modules. I've already searched for solutions online and the best solution i could find is to import all functions explicitly with `from mymodule import (myfunc_1, myfunc_2, ...)`, however that seems a bit too much since I have ~3 modules with ~2000 lines of code and a bunch of functions. So i wanted to ask how, if there is a way, to do it more efficiantly

Comment: You should add more detail, such as the folder structure to increase your chances of getting a  useful answer.

Comment: If you have circular dependencies, it doesn't matter if you use `import *` vs `import (a,b,c)`.  Fix the dependencies first.

Comment: You could do a straight import with `import module1` (or even `import module1 as m1` for a shorter reference name) and then reference the functions later with `module1.some_func` (or `m1.some_func`), which avoids having to `from x import y` a million times.